# Excel using pivot table count in another formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, excel-2010, pivot-table

Anybody has an idea why i cant use pivot table count value that is a number for a calculated field in that same pivot table?
Here is the picture of what i mean:

[Count field in the pivot table counts how many of the certain Models are in a table and i would need to use the following formula: Count divided by Sum of IN in this pivot table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx3tt.png)

Every time i try to use the value from "Count" column it returns the #VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a formatting issue where excel is not understanding that one of the numbers is a number. There are a couple of ways to address the issue.

1. Highlight the cells, Home>Number, then apply the number format.
   [image: Home>Number]
2. Select the pivot table,

   1. in the pivot table fields box, select the dropdown arrow in the values section and select `Value Field Settings` 
      [image: Value Field Settings]
   2. Then select `Number Format` and then choose the desired formatting (likely `Number`) 
      [image: Number Format]
3. Force it as a value in your formula.

   1. I assume your formula looks something like

      1. `=D4/C4` or
      2. `=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Sum",$A$3,"Top","Top","Name","Bottom
         ")/GETPIVOTDATA("Count of Count",$A$3,"Top","Top","Name","Bottom ")`
   2. you can use the `VALUE()` function to create

      1. `=VALUE(D4)/VALUE(C4)` or
      2. `=VALUE(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Sum",$A$3,"Top","Top","Name","Bottom
         "))/VALUE(GETPIVOTDATA("Count of
         Count",$A$3,"Top","Top","Name","Bottom "))`
4. Create a new 'Calculated Field' in your pivot table that does the function for you.

   1. Select the pivot table, then `Analyze>Calculations>Fields Items & Sets>Calculated Field`
      [image: Analyze>Calculations>Fields Items & Sets>Calculated Field]
   2. Give your field a name, then for your formula, enter something along the lines of `Count/Sum of IN`. Use the `Fields` box to make sure you get the Field names right
      [image: Calculated Field Options]

Hopefully one of these options will help you get what you need.